# How to keep the height of element equals to 2 lines?

Tags: html, css

I know if I want an element has 2 lines of text only, it can be done like this:

```html
<span style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;-webkit-line-clamp:2;display:-webkit-box;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;"><b>Long title! Long title! Long title! Long title! Long title! Long title! Long title! Long title! Long title! Long title! Long title! Long title! Long title! Long title! Long title! Long title! Long title! </b></span>
<span>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/></span>
```

but if the text is short, it would have 1 line only:

```html
<span style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;-webkit-line-clamp:2;display:-webkit-box;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;"><b>Short title! </b></span>
     <span>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/></span>
```

now I want an element would have 2 line heights even it has actually 1 line only, looking like this:

```html
<span style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;-webkit-line-clamp:2;display:-webkit-box;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;"><b>Short title! </b></span><br/>
 <span>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/></span>
```

and I want to do it in responsive way,ie: regardless of the length of the title, the < span> would always have the height equal to 2 lines of text (which the height depends on font size only, but not the fix px), can it be done in css?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `em` sizes instead of `px`.

here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/x2t559ar/